# UIActivityViewController - Close Button vs Slidedown

Tags: swiftui, uiactivityviewcontroller

I noticed that there is a difference in the behavior of the UIActivityViewController when :

1: press the CLOSE (X) button up there, or
2: do a SLIDE DOWN to do the dismiss.

Pressing the button returns a nil value in activityType, doing a slidedown it returns nothing.

So I can't dismiss the ProgressView when I do a slide down.
Do you have any tips ?

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    vm.showShareProgress.toggle()
                    vm.showShareAV.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("share")
            }
            if vm.showShareProgress {
                ProgressView()
                    .padding()
                    .background(.thinMaterial)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .transition(.scale)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $vm.showShareAV, content: { ActivityViewController(itemsToShare: [vm.contentToShare as Any]) })
        .environmentObject(vm)
    }
}

final class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var showShareAV: Bool = false
    @Published var showShareProgress = false
    
    @Published var contentToShare: Any?
        
}

struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: MainViewModel
    
    var itemsToShare: [Any]
    var servicesToShareItem: [UIActivity]? = nil
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) -> UIActivityViewController {
        
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: itemsToShare, applicationActivities: servicesToShareItem)
        
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, arrayReturnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
            
            print("Sharing activity : \(String(describing: activityType?.rawValue))")
            
            if completed { print("sharing OK") }
            else { print("sharing canceled") }
            
            if let sharingError = error { print("Sharing error : \(sharingError.localizedDescription)") }
            
            vm.showShareProgress = false
            
        }
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) {}
    
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(MainViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see necessity of `shareShareProgress` at all - you can just use same `showShareAV` as activator, but even with used two - `shareShareProgress` can be activated just `onChange(of: showShareAV)`. Although it looks like a bug of UIActivityViewController - completion handler must be called on any dismiss.

Comment: Hi @Asperi, thank you for your answer.
The need of a ProgressView there is because I'm creating a PNG that takes between 1 to 3 seconds to be created. It takes time to process... Ideally I would not implement that of course, but the wait is terrible without knowing what's happening.